# What event is fired when the controls are toggled in Blueimp Gallery?

Tags: jquery, carousel, blueimp

I'm trying to animate the controls as they appear. What's the event that's fired when you hit enter or click on the gallery and toggle the controls? I went through the docs but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I edited the js and added a trigger myself.